# Inverse Laplace transform of $R(s)$

Tags: integral-transforms, inverse-laplace

> Calculate the Inverse Laplace transform of
> $$R(s)=\frac{s^3+s^2+2}{s^2-1}.$$

I have split it into
$$\frac{s^3+s^2+2}{s^2-1}=s+1-\frac{1}{s+1}+\frac{2}{s-1},$$
but I am facing difficulty to find the Inverse Laplace Transform of the first part
$$s+1.$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using Table

Comment: is this correct L-1 [ s+1]=  δ' (t)+ u(t)

Comment: L-1 [ s+1]=  δ' (t)+ u(t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your partial fraction expansion. We have:

$$s+1 + \dfrac{2}{s-1}-\dfrac{1}{s+1}$$

Using this table of [*Laplace transforms*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf), we find:

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left(s+1 + \dfrac{2}{s-1}-\dfrac{1}{s+1}\right) = 
\delta'(t) + \delta(t) + 2 e^t - e^{-t}$$

You are going to have to think through the first two as they are a bit tricky.